# Подключить файл из директории на уровень выше директории сайта

Tags: php

А вот этого до сих пор и не знаю.

К примеру `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` выдает путь `/var/www/some/data/www/site.com`

Допустим в директорию www в которой находится `site.com` закинули файлик `some.php`

Как допустим из `index.php` который находится в директории `site.com` подключить заветный файлик `some.php`, то есть как верно указать сам путь к данному файлу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require_once(realpath('../some.php'));
```

Comment: ха) а я то думал все как то сложнее делается)

Answer (score 2):

Написать в index.php:

```
include('../some.php');
```